# How can I move objects on to positions declared by their clicking order?

Tags: corona-sdk

I'm trying to create a quiz game with clickable letters. How can I move them to another area based on their clicking order?

[image: example picture]

Though you probably already understand what I'm trying to ask, lets clarify:
If I was to click the "H" letter first, it would move to the first white box, clicking "O" after that, would move it to the second white box etc.

Comment: There are really too many ways to implement this. For example you could have a counter that will tell you the next position the clicked letter should go to.

Answer (score 0):

Like @zoran404 commented there are a lot of ways to implement it, but I would proceed with the counter as well, doing something like this:

```
-- you either have a function for each letter or have a class and turn this into a method
-- but the process is similar

-- create a table with all the free spaces' coordinates
-- and a counter to check the first free space
-- remember in lua arrays start at 1
local spaces = {}
local i = 1

local function increaseCounter()
    i = i + 1
end

local function letter:onClick( listener )
     transition.to( letter, { x = spaces[i].x, y = spaces[i].y } )
     -- check documentation for info (docs.coronalabs.com)
     increaseCounter()
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know which language u are using but in JS i would do something like:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>


$(".letter").on("click", function(){
  $(".box").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).attr("filled")){
      $(this).attr("filled",true);
      fillTheGap();
      break;
    }
  });
});
```